# Showing a general list of booked users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I created an application where users can book a hour of training. I want to give to admin users the option to see a general list of booked users in every training hour.

Im trying to create this index, but it gives me the following error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Trainings#index
>
> No route
> matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bookings", :training_id=>nil}
> missing required keys: [:training_id]

Im trying to create this button at index of training, like this:

training index.html.erb view:

```
<h1>Hours</h1>

<ul class="trainings">
  <% @trainings.each do |training| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to training.hour, training_path(training) %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= render 'bookings/general_list' if logged_in? %>
```

_general_list.html.erb view:

```
<ul class="bookings">
<% @trainings.each do |training| %>
<%= link_to "General list", training_bookings_path(@training), class: "btn btn-primary"  %>    
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I would like to now how i can get this done, i think my idea is not working.

my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :users
  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

rake routes command:

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
                   root GET    /                                                   static_pages#home
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                   users#new
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                                  static_pages#contact
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                                    static_pages#about
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                                    sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                                    sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                   sessions#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)             account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)                          password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)                      password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                 password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                                    users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                                    users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                           users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                users#destroy
      training_bookings GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#index
                        POST   /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#create
   new_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/new(.:format)      bookings#new
  edit_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format) bookings#edit
       training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#destroy
              trainings GET    /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#index
                        POST   /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#create
           new_training GET    /trainings/new(.:format)                            trainings#new
          edit_training GET    /trainings/:id/edit(.:format)                       trainings#edit
               training GET    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#destroy
```

Thanks.

Comment: What shows `rake routes`?

Comment: Updated with rake routes command

Comment: It migth be the `training_bookings_path(@training)` that requieres a `:training_id`

Comment: how should i implemente that? training_bookings_path(@training, :training_id) ?

Comment: You need a @booking instance, do you have one?

Comment: where do i have to instace @booking? i did not understand you :-(

Answer (score 0):

In `_general_list.html.erb` you should change `@training` for `training`